# Wann verwendet man "machen" und "lassen"?

Tags: grammar, verb, verb-usage, verb-choice

Viele Nicht-Muttersprachler machen immer die Fehler, wenn sie "sth./ sb makes/causes sth./ sb to do something" sagen wollen :

> z.B.  Der Tod meiner Mutter macht mich traurig.

Kann man auch in diesem Zusammenhang "lassen" verwenden? Aber muss man den Satz so umschreiben :

> z.B. Der Tod meiner Mutter lässt mich traurig fühlen.

Meine Frage ist :  Wann verwendet man "machen" und "lassen" und in welchem Zusammenhang werden sie benutzt?

Comment: Meine Vermutung wäre, dass das in erster Linie nur ein Problem für Englisch-Muttersprachler ist...

Comment: Der erste Beispielsatz folgt ja gar nicht dem Muster; da fehlt der Infinitiv aus _causes someone **to do** something_.